# How to set the tittle attribute value based on the value in a map?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add for every words existing as a key in a given map a span tag. I did like that:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(json)));
const words = [...map.keys()];

var data = document.getElementById("num1").value
$('#fake_textarea').html(data);


// create a regular expression matching any of these words, using 'g' flag to match all instances
var regexp = new RegExp('(' + words.join('|') + ')', 'ig');

$('#fake_textarea').each(function (num, elem) {

  var text = $(elem).text();

  // use string.replace with $& notation to indicate whatever was matched
  text = text.replace(regexp, `<span title="$&" id="$&" style="color:red;"><b>$&</b></span>`);
  $(elem).html(text);
});
```

It works well. how I can add for every added span the title attribute with the correspondig value in the map. let say for a given word `key` I need to add the attribute `<span title=value of key in the map`> key. For example:

[image]

and my map is: [image]

So I need to replace the tooltip of boy that displays `boy` by `Mr`.

Indeed, how to match words consisting of two words?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with a function as a replacer:

```js
const html = $('#fake_textarea').val().replace(
    /\p{L}+/gu, // Match every word respecting Unicode letters
    word => {
        const wordLowercased = word.toLowerCase();

        if (!map.has(wordLowercased)) {
            return word;
        }

        return $('<span>')
            .text(word)
            .attr('title', map.get(wordLowercased))
            .css({
                color: 'red',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
            })
            .prop('outerHTML');
    }
);
```

Make sure all your words in the `map` are lowercased to match them.

Notice that I match every word instead of producing one long regex pattern. Doing the latter can lead to wrong results if there are special characters in the `map` or, what's even worse, could crash your app if the regex turns out to be wrong (using some special characters in the pattern, like `{` without closing `}`).

Comment: can you please change the val() by text() to be accept your answer?

Comment: Isn't `val()` the way to go with `textarea`?

Comment: Yeah you have reason. Please, how can update the regex to match keys in the map that consist of multiple words. Let say instead we have in the map a key: big boy with value: prof.